# Laravel 6 Eloquent - Relationship between three tables and pivots

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, pivot-table

I have three tables and I want to relationate all of 3 but I don't know how.

I have a table for the users and two more for the posts and categories, also categories stores categories and subcategories on same table (with a type column to separate).

Posts and users have a pivot table and posts and categories too. But I want to get user posts through the categories like:

Category  or Subcategory -> Post -> User

**Category model:**

```
class Category extends Model
{

    protected $fillable = ['name', 'description', 'type', 'category_id','post_id'];

    public function posts() {

        return $this->belongsToMany(Post::class)->withPivot('post_id');

    }
}
```

**Post model:**

```
class Post extends Model {

    public function users() {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'post_user','post_id', 'user_id')->withTimestamps();
    }


    public function categories() {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Category::class)->withPivot('category_id');
    }
```

**User model:**

```
class User extends Authenticatable {

    public function posts() {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Post::class, 'post_user', 'user_id', 'post_id')->withTimestamps();
    }
```

Then in the controller I only have this

`$posts = Category::with('posts')->get();`

I don't know how to relate these 3 tables. Maybe I need to make only one pivot table between the 3 tables?

Edit: Thanks to **Qirel** to help me to relate the tables:

`Category::with('posts.users');`

Then I want to show only the categories where an specific user has posts, for example something like

`Category::with('posts.users')->where('user.id',1);`

It is possible?

Comment: You can nest relations, like `Category::with('posts.users');` (eager loading on both `posts` and `posts.users` relation). The user is related to the post, so there should be a `post_user` pivot, and a category is linked to a post, so there should be a `category_post` pivot table. And by joining these together, you can find out which users has posted in which categories, or vice versa.

Comment: Then I can show the categories where a user have a post? Like ```post.users where id = 1?```

Comment: Yes, `Category::with('posts.users')->whereHas("posts.users", function($query) { $query->where("id", 1); });` or `Category::with('posts.users', function($query) { $query->where("id", 1); });` (one just filters the relation data and selects the category anyways, the other checks if there is relation data).

Comment: In both options returns this: 

```SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'id' in where clause is ambiguous (SQL: select * from `categories` where exists (select * from `posts` inner join `category_post` on `posts`.`id` = `category_post`.`post_id` where `categories`.`id` = `category_post`.`category_id` and exists (select * from `users` inner join `post_user` on `users`.`id` = `post_user`.`user_id` where `posts`.`id` = `post_user`.`post_id` and `id` = 1)))
```

Comment: Do you have an `id` column in either `category_post` or `post_user`?

Comment: On ```category_post``` I have ```category_id``` and ```post_id``` and in ```post_user``` ```post_id``` and ```user_id```

Comment: But do either of those columns have an `id` field, like an auto-increment? It should not have that on either pivot table.

Comment: Ok, I'm gonna delete these id columns on both pivot tables.

Comment: Now I get this: ```mb_strpos() expects parameter 1 to be string``` on 

```$posts = Category::with('posts.users', function($query) { $query->where("id", 1); })->get();```

Comment: Whoops, that should be an array, `with(['posts.users' =>  function($query) { ... }])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, this can be achieved through nested relations.

Using eager loading to "pre-load" the relational data by using `with()`, and a relation-condition by using `whereHas()` with the filter you desire, ensures that you only obtain records where there is a relation matching that condition - in your case, it will only load the categories where a specific user has posted.

```
$user_id = 1;
Category::with('posts.users')
        ->whereHas("posts.users", function($query) use ($user_id) { 
            $query->where("id", $user_id); 
        })
        ->get();
```

You can also get all categories (regardless if the provided user has posted or not), but limit the relational data to only be from that user (meaning you get all categories, but just the posts where the user with ID 1 is the poster). You can achieve this by putting a condition on the eager loading (notice that unlike using `whereHas()` above, this is a key/value paired array now).

```
$user_id = 1;
Category::with(['posts.users' => function($query) use ($user_id) { 
            $query->where("id", $user_id); 
        }])
        ->get();
```